# How to handle irregular updates with tqdm

Tags: python, tqdm

I'm using [tqdm](https://tqdm.github.io/) for showing a progress bar while something is loading. While some steps are quite fast, others can take several seconds or even minutes. What I'm experiencing is that the estimated remaining time is also jumping between minutes (if a few quick steps occurred) and hours (after a few slow steps). The truth that I would like to show to the user is somewhere in-between.

I'm wondering if tqdm has an option to tell that the remaining time should be computed as a global average? Say if it took 10 minutes for 100 out of 400 steps (regardless if the last couple of steps were fast or slow), that the estimated remaining time is simply 40 minutes?

Is [`smoothing=0`](https://tqdm.github.io/docs/tqdm/#__init__) the parameter to set in these cases? The documentation is a bit confusing, as it states

> **smoothing**: float, optional
>
> Exponential moving average smoothing factor for speed estimates (ignored in GUI mode). Ranges from 0 (average speed) to 1 (current/instantaneous speed) [default: 0.3].

Is that just the "speed"? And does the estimated remaining time change accordingly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tested the following code and `smoothing=0` is indeed the parameter to go.

Consider the following snippet and watch how the progress bar is more helpful with `smoothing=0` when updates are highly irregular:

```
from time import sleep
from tqdm import tqdm
import random

# Default smoothing of 0.3 - irregular updates and medium-useful ETA
for i in tqdm(range(100)):
    sleep(random.randint(0,5)/10)

# Immediate updates - not useful for irregular updates
for i in tqdm(range(100), smoothing=1):
    sleep(random.randint(0,5)/10)

# Global smoothing - most useful ETA in this scenario
for i in tqdm(range(100), smoothing=0):
    sleep(random.randint(0,5)/10)
```